# Open Modal and Page with cypress and Ionic 3

Tags: angular, testing, ionic3, e2e-testing, cypress

I build an Ionic 3 project and I want to test it with Cypress. I can access to my app and run some simple test. But when I try open page of modal, nothing append and my test fail.

```
it('should open history', () => {
        // Button to open my page : OK
        cy.get(open_history_button).click();

        // Check if a label exists in the opened page : FAIL
        cy.get(history_no_event_label).contains("All is ok !");
    });
```

Cypress success to click on the button but the page doesn't appear.

Someone have an idea to solve that ?

Comment: You can try adding a small wait after the click `cy.wait(500)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ok ! I understand my mistake.
I my code I used (tap) to do on click event. But it doesn't works with cypress.
So I replace all my (tap) by (click) and it works better.

```
<button ion-button (tap)="doSomething()">My Button</button> => WRONG
<button ion-button (click)="doSomething()">My Button</button> => GOOD
```